# How to properly use ScrollView in Kivy Python?

Tags: python, scroll, grid, kivy, grid-layout

I have this code where i want to change the position of the buttons, but if i change the position, the scroll is no longer working. How to manage to make it work? Below is the working version. If i change size_hint: 1, .1 to size_hint: 1, .7, the scroll no longer works...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1, .1
        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            cols: 1
            # minimum_height: self.height
            Button
                text: 'one'
            Button:
                text: 'two'
            Button:
                text: 'three'
            Button:
                text: 'four'
''')

class Root(FloatLayout):
    pass

class DemoApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right. The `ScrollView` allows you to scroll to see parts of your `GridLayout` that don't fit in the `ScrollView`. When you set the `size_hint` to `(1, .7)`, everything fits within the `ScrollView`, so it does not scroll.

You can force scrolling by adding `Widgets` to take up more space (like `Labels` with no text):

```
<Root>:
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1, .7
        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            cols: 1
            height: self.minimum_height
            Label:
                text: ''
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 300
            Button
                text: 'one'
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
            Button:
                text: 'two'
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
            Button:
                text: 'three'
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
            Button:
                text: 'four'
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
            Label:
                text: ''
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Once theres a `size_hint_y = None` in the parent widget, then you have to manually declare the height of the child widget since **size_hint_y** deals with the height or Y axis.. so i modified your code to make things a lil clearer

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y:None
        height:root.width / 2
        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            cols: 1
            height:self.minimum_height
            spacing:dp(20)
            Button
                text: 'one'
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(50)
            Button:
                text: 'two'
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(50)
            Button:
                text: 'three'
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(50)
            Button:
                text: 'four'
                size_hint_y:None
                height:dp(50)
''')

class Root(FloatLayout):
    pass

class DemoApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```